# How to change localhost to ping 127.0.0.1

Tags: windows-xp, localhost

I am using windows xp sp2. Whenever i ping localhost it resolves to ::1 if network cable is connected. If i remove network cable then localhost resolves to 127.0.0.1. I do not know about this strange behaviour of localhost. Google do not help me on this. I want localhost needs to resolve 127.0.0.1 without touching IPv6. My another machine has IPv6 but in that localhost always points to 127.0.0.1.

Comment: Just as an aside, if you are really running SP2, you need to immediately disconnect your computer from the Internet. If you are running SP3 and all additional patches, you are ok until April, 2014.

Comment: I don't use internet on that machine. In my case I connected my system in LAN.

Comment: Sounds like you have a DNS server that is translating “localhost” to `::1`, and you get `127.0.0.1` only when you fall back to your `hosts` file. Is your other machine on the same network? pointing to the same DNS server?

Comment: have you disabled IPv6 in your network adapters protocol binding and configuration dialog? just uncheck the box for 'Internet Protocol v6'

Comment: `Just as an aside, if you are really running SP2, you need to immediately disconnect your computer from the Internet. If you are running SP3 and all additional patches, you are ok until April, 2014` Really‽ ⊙▃⊙ Then what happens? Do they have to disconnect in April? Can they use the Internet ever again? ఠ_ఠ (For the record, I still use XP SP1 but my system hasn’t exploded or melted yet.)

Comment: `> KaRTHICK: …without touching IPv6.`    @FrankThomas: `have you disabled IPv6 in your network adapters protocol binding and configuration dialog? just uncheck the box for 'Internet Protocol v6` I don’t think that’s what they’re looking for.

Comment: @KaRTHICK, check your [HOSTS file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hosts_(file)#Location_in_the_file_system), it probably has an IPv6 versions, so if you remove that but leave the IPv4 version, it should always resolve as you want.